# Storing byte[] into varbinary(MAX) in SQL Server From Android Through PHP

Tags: php, android, sql-server, varbinary, varbinarymax

I am using SQL Server (MSSQL) DB, a table CUST_BIO has a column CustData of datatype varbinary(MAX). I am using Android App to store data in this column using PHP.

```
  public function registerCust($custId, $custData)
  {


    $sqlString = "INSERT INTO CUST_BIO (CustId,CustData ) values (? ,? ) ; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
    $params    = array($custId,  $custData );

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $sqlString, $params);
    if ($stmt === false) {

        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt);
    $lastId = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0);

    echo "\nLast Inserted Id : " . $lastId . "\n";

    }
```

This gave me the error :

**Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.**

So i changed

the line

```
$params    = array($custId,  $custData );
```

to

```
$params    = array($custId, CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), $custData );
```

After updating this code , it gave me another error;

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function CONVERT()**

I am sending byte[] from Android to PHP webservice and storing it in **$custData** variable.

I am trying to store an image into the DB, there are a lot of suggestions on the other forums which says it is not the efficient way but I have limitations to use this way.

Can Anyone Guide me solving this problem?

Comment: CONVERT is mssql function you're using it on php

Comment: @SaadSuri : ok. what can i use in PHP?

Comment: Use `binary` `$params = array($custId,  (binary)$custData );`

Comment: @SaadSuri : Same error after using (binary)
Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed.